# Would convolutional neural networks be spatially invariant if we didn't feed it images of objects that appear in different locations?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

If we are building a cat classifier and we fed the CNN images of cats that appear in the same location in the training images. Would the CNN work during inference if we gave it an image of a cat in a different location in the image?

By "work" I mean (give a good performance as if we fed the CNN images of cats in different locations in the input images)

Comment: Please clarify your definition of "would the CNN work", as stated it seems ambiguous.Is it intended to ask whether even a single cat image would be properly recognized or not? Or does it mean whether the performance would deteriorate as compared to the same network trained on cats placed at different locations in the image?

Comment: Yes. I mean it as "whether the performance would deteriorate as compared to the same network trained on cats placed at different locations in the image"